# Smack java server (jar file) How to deploy it and use it from the smack server

Tags: java, xmpp

I have finished implementation of XMPP/smack server in java, Now I have jar file(implementaion of server) at my local machine, now I want to move this file to XMPP server (that is ready). How may I do that, how to call my methods from Smack server??

Comment: I face the same problem, and I now think to re-program my server with php and send my java server to the cyrcle bin!! :(